# Comment box textarea showing default text that goes away when the user focuses it

Tags: javascript, css, comments

Hey guys, I'm creating a comment box and I want to do two stuff to the comment box which I think need javascript, but I'm not really a pro using javascript yet. I want the comment box to show some text in it saying (type in your comment) and when the user clicks it, the text disappears. And also, I want to show a submit button only when the user clicks on the comment box, do you know any way I can do that?

Comment: Plain JavaScript, or are you using a library (jQuery, MooTools, Prototype, Glow, etc...)?

Comment: It seems people can't wait to vote to close a question.  Seriously can we tone it down, SO Police!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have put up [a page showing how to do this](http://phrogz.net/JS/self-describing-inputs.html) with plain JavaScript. I've abstracted the code for having text inputs/areas show instructional text until focused.

In general:

- watch the `focus` and `blur` events on the input and change the value (and optionally classes) based on the existing value/'helpful' value.
- watch the `focus` and `blur` of the comment box and change the CSS class of another element to show and hide it.

This is all a good bit easier if you use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), since it already includes cross-browser code and even plugins to handle the self-describing part. If you're open to using jQuery, let me know and I'll give you an updated answer using that.

**Edit**: OK, I've added a [jQuery version of the example](http://phrogz.net/js/self-describing-inputs-jquery.html). I decided not to use a plugin for the self-description since it is only 8 lines. I also changed that particular example to use the `title` attribute to hold the default text to display.

**Edit #2**: Based on the problem @Meke pointed out, I've made a minor update to the scripts to handle the case where FireFox reloads the page and leaves the default text in place, and then (previously) didn't properly add the class to indicate that this was default text.

I should also note that neither of my examples include a `submit` event handler for the form to remove the value for inputs that happen to still be showing the default value. This (rather trivial code) is something you would want to add.

Also note that by actually changing the `value` of the input/textarea code like this may break form validation not prepared to understand it.

Comment: Compliments for doing all that in pure JS.

Comment: Yea if you could post the jQuery example I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @SamGabriel I've added the example. Since you appear to be new to stackoverflow, I'll let you know that if you find an answer has solved your question you should accept it (big checkmark) so that others know it's the answer you recommend.

Comment: @Phrogz - Noticed your jQuery version doesn't appreciate page reloads, posting a working one I just wrote.

Comment: Just one thing, I can't seem to be able to actually click the submit button, why is that?

Comment: @SamGabriel Because my example code hides the submit button when you defocus the textarea. Because the `blur` of the textarea fires before the `click` of the submit button, it disappears out from under you. I would never personally advocate this, nor would I even hide the submit button until the comment box was shown. I was implementing what I thought you asked for. It's up to you to decide what usability you want to encourage or destroy with the tools in your hands.

Comment: So it's not possible to do this and let me actually click the comment button?

Answer (score 0):

As Phrogz jQuery version doesn't play well with reloads I decided to make my own based on what I knew, as such, here it is:

All you need to do is place a "placeholder=[text]" in your input to get it to show up (This name was picked as HTML5 uses "placeholder" for the very same function.

```
    $('input:text').each(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).css('color','#900');
            $(this).focus(function(){
                // If value is same as 'placeholder', clear field
                if($(this).val() === $(this).attr('placeholder')){
                    $(this).val('').css('color','#000');
                } else { // Else select the whole text (one less click)
                    $(this).select();
                }
            });
            $(this).blur(function(){
                // On blur, if empty field, put placeholder back
                if ($(this).val() === ''){
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).css('color','#900');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't play well with page reloads"? What steps did you perform, on what OS/browser/version, and what did it do other than what you expected?

Comment: Wrote something in top field, reloaded. Text stayed, lower field text went black instead of grey. Using OS X, FF, latest.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed this in mine.